# jQuery param() chokes on object with functions in it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In the .error() of a ajax call, I'm getting an object back, with functions, inside it.  It looks like it's the ajax() object itself...
`abort(),always(),complete()`, etc etc.
if I do

```
var qstring = jQuery.param(data);
```

I get syntax error and everything crashes.
I tried:

```
var qstring = jQuery.param(jQuery.makeArray( data ))
```

and i just get 'undefined'

What I am trying to do is send the result of the error, along with the original arguments that I ajax'd, to my error.php:

here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax(ajaxargs).done(function (data) {
    //success, do things with data
}).error(function (data) {
        console.log(data);//this is an object with functions
        $.fn.crMap.ajaxFail(data, 'mycall', ajaxargs);
    });
```

and my failure function:

```
$.fn.crMap.ajaxFail = function (data, call, ajaxargs) {     
    var out = {
        call: call,
        ajaxFail: 'complete',
        ajaxargs: ajaxargs
        returned: data
    }
    document.location = '/error.php?'+ jQuery.param(out) ;
};
```

which works, if I dont try to pass in the data.  Any attempt to .param(data) causes syntax error, or actually, a `TypeError: a is undefined`, deep in jquery.js

Comment: what is `data`? how is `$.fn.crMap.ajaxFail` called... the ajax fail handlers won't give the returned data as an argument

Comment: @ArunPJohny, edited to show ajax call.  It does seem to be giving me something, in the data, like staus: 403, statusText: Forbidden, etc.  (I am simulating the error by returning 403 from the ajax target)

Comment: In the fail handler.... the first argument is not the data... it is the jqXHR object.... what are you expecting there

Comment: I expected the 'data' to be whatever errors the ajax ran into, which caused the error.  (I didnt know, I thought i'd output it and see).  The fact that status and statusText are in there is what I was expecting.  I just want to send something to my error.php to try to troubleshoot it.  I had a hard time figuring out anything about the .error() function.